# Jenkins is checking out the entire SVN repo twice

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline setup, and a Jenkins file which has the below content:

```
 pipeline {
    agent any 

    stages {

        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                echo 'Hey'
            } 
        }
    }  
}
```

A post commit hook triggers the Jenkins build successfully, and I can see it starting from the Jenkins UI. It states that it is checking out the repo to read from the Jenkins file and it stores the checkout in the `workspace@script` folder on the server.

```
Checking out svn https://<svn_server>/svn/Test/Core into C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI_Build\workspace@script to read JenkinsPipeline/Jenkinsfile
Checking out a fresh workspace because C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CI_Build\workspace@script doesn't exist
Cleaning local Directory .
```

After this is complete, I make a change to a file in the repo and the build triggers via the post commit hook happily, but then it tries to checkout the entire code base again into a folder called `workspace`. I would have expected that the checkout happens once and then the "use SVN update as much as possible" option would kick in and only update the changed files? Or maybe I have the wrong logic?

SVN version - 1.9.7

Jenkins version - 2.84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins has to know what is in your pipeline script before it knows if it should checkout your code. It is possible that your pipeline says not to check out the code, and you set into a subdirectory and fire off the checkout yourself. Or maybe checkout multiple repos in different places. Until Jenkins sees your Jenkinsfile, it can't know what you want. So it has to checkout the repo once to see your pipeline, then again to do the work.

With git (and maybe some versions of other repo plugins) lightweight or sparse checkouts are supported, so then it only grabs the jenkinsfile instead of the entire repo. I don't think this is a supported option in SVN yet.

Comment: That makes more sense now. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Lightweight checkouts are now supported by the SVN plugin, the SVN plugin was updated in version 2.12.0 to add this feature - see https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin.